# Switch music playing from iPod to Mac when getting home

Tags: itunes, mac, ipod-touch, music, remote.app

is there a way to automatically 'transfer' the music you hear on your iPod touch (4. generation) to the Mac?

What I want to do:

I am listening to music while I am on my way back home. I get home and my iPod touch connects to my access point. My Mac is awake and could be directed to play music via Remote on my iPod touch.

Can I sync both devices so they play the same song at the same time, so I can turn off my iPod and put away my headphones, but continue listening via my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Funny question - never loose the flow...

The only way I see is that you install a tool like [Airfoil](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) and have your Mac simulate an AirPlay device. Then once you get home and your iPod is logged into your WiFi you could select your Mac as the speaker.

Comment: The idea sounds good. Let's see if there will come any further replies.

Comment: I tried it. The demo supports just 10 minutes until it adds noise, but thats not the problem. Until then I have a new song started on my Mac :D

The only problem I have is that I have to switch the AirPlay device. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: @Frozn You mean that you have to select the AirPlay speakers? Well now I'm out. Get an iPhone, VPN to your home, start iTunes with the remote app ;)